# Android App does not start methods ()

Tags: java, android, class, methods

I know, its much code. But its easy to read and simple to understand. My problem is that the app does not start the spielernamen(); ingame(); methods and I have no idea why. Its a simple game.
I also dont understand why at first the method rundenanzahl(); is called. Shouldnt it be variante(); ?
Thanks alot for ur help guys.

```
 package silverbeach.wuerfelspiel;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button spielregeln;
    Button neuesSpiel;
    Button beenden;
    Button wuerfel;
    TextView regeln;
    int Runden;
    int Variante;
    int aktSpieler;
    int Spieleranzahl;
    Spieler[] Spielerdaten;
    EditText input;
    EditText input2;
    TextView textviewUP;
    TextView textviewDOWN;
    TextView textviewMID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spielregeln = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_regeln);
        neuesSpiel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_neuesSpiel);
        beenden = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_beenden);
        wuerfel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        regeln = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textviewUP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textviewDOWN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textviewMID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);


        neuesSpiel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spielregeln.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        beenden.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        spielregeln.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                builder.setTitle("Spielregeln");
                builder.setMessage("Variante 1: Alle Augen werden gewertet\n" +
                        "Variante 2: Nur gerade Augen werden gewertet\n" +
                        "Variante 3: Wie Variante 1, aber bei der Augenzahl '1' wird die Gesamtsumme zurückgesetzt\n\n" +
                        "Nach Eingabe der Spieleranzahl (max. 8) und Spielernamen beginnt die Partie.\n" +
                        "Es wird so oft gewürfelt, wie Spielrunden(max. 16) angegeben wurden.\n" +
                        "Sind die Würfelrunden vorbei, wird die Augensumme für jeden Spieler festgestellt und ein Sieger ausgewertet."
                );
                builder.setPositiveButton("Verstanden, los geht's!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                final AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
                ad.show();
            }
        });

        neuesSpiel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                neuesSpiel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                spielregeln.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                beenden.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                variante();
                spieleranzahl();
                rundenanzahl();
                spielernamen();
                ingame();
            }
        });}


    public int wuerfeln() {
        int zahl = (int) ((Math.random()) * 6 + 1);
        return zahl;
    }

    public void variante() {

       // Spieler sieger = new Spieler();

        //Variante eingeben
        AlertDialog.Builder builder_variante = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder_variante.setTitle("Variante auswählen");
        builder_variante.setMessage("Bitte geben Sie die gewünschte Variantennummer an.");
        input = new EditText(this);
        builder_variante.setView(input);

        //POSITIVE
        builder_variante.setPositiveButton("Bestätigen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                int var = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
                setVariante(var);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog ad_variante = builder_variante.create();
        ad_variante.show();}

public void spieleranzahl() {
        //Spieleranzahl eingeben
        AlertDialog.Builder builder_spieleranzahl = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder_spieleranzahl.setTitle("Turniergröße");
    builder_spieleranzahl.setMessage("Wie biele Spieler wollen gegeneinander antreten?");
        input = new EditText(this);
    builder_spieleranzahl.setView(input);

        //POSITIVE
    builder_spieleranzahl.setPositiveButton("Bestätigen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                int sp = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
                setSpieleranzahl(sp);
            }
        });
    AlertDialog ad_spieleranzahl = builder_spieleranzahl.create();
    ad_spieleranzahl.show();
}

public void rundenanzahl() {
    //Rundenanzahl - max.8
    AlertDialog.Builder builder_rundenanzahl = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder_rundenanzahl.setTitle("Rundenanzahl");
    builder_rundenanzahl.setMessage("Wie viele Durchläufe wollen sie spielen?");
    input = new EditText(this);
    builder_rundenanzahl.setView(input);

    //POSITIVE
    builder_rundenanzahl.setPositiveButton("Bestätigen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            int rnd = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
            setRunden(rnd);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog ad_rundenanzahl = builder_rundenanzahl.create();
    ad_rundenanzahl.show();
}

public void spielernamen(){
        //Spielernamen eingeben
        Spielerdaten = new Spieler[Spieleranzahl];
        for (int i = 0; i < Spieleranzahl; i++) {
            final Spieler spieler = new Spieler();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder_spielernamen = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder_spielernamen.setTitle(("Spieler: " + (i + 1)));
            builder_spielernamen.setMessage("Bitte geben Sie ihren Namen ein um fortzufahren.");

            input2 = new EditText(this);
            builder_spielernamen.setView(input2);
            //POSITIVE
            builder_spielernamen.setPositiveButton("Bestätigen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String name;
                    name = input2.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    spieler.setName(name);

                }
            });
            builder_spielernamen.show();



            Spielerdaten[i] = spieler;
        }}


        public void ingame(){
        int aktRunde = 0;
        //buffer, damit nicht direkt nächste eingabe ausgeführt wird
        // in.nextLine();
        while (aktRunde < Runden) {
            for (aktSpieler = 0; aktSpieler < Spieleranzahl; aktSpieler++) {

                textviewUP.setText((aktRunde + 1) + " - " + Spielerdaten[aktSpieler].getName() + " ist am Zug");
                textviewDOWN.setText("Drücke EINGABETASTE um zu würfeln!");
                wuerfel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               wuerfel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       int augen;
                       augen = wuerfeln();
                       textviewDOWN.setText("gewürfelte Augen: " + augen + "\n");



                switch (Variante) {
                    //einfache additiond er augen
                    case 1: {
                        Spielerdaten[aktSpieler].addAugen(augen);
                    }
                    break;
                    case 2: {
                        if (augen % 2 == 0) Spielerdaten[aktSpieler].addAugen(augen);
                        else System.out.println("\t->Leider keine gerade Zahl :(\n");
                    }
                    break;
                    case 3: {
                        if (augen == 1) {
                            textviewDOWN.setText("Oh nein, die böse 1 - alle Punkte werden gelöscht");
                            Spielerdaten[aktSpieler].resetSumme();
                        } else Spielerdaten[aktSpieler].addAugen(augen);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }});
            aktRunde++;
        }
        textviewUP.setText("AUSWERTUNG:");
            Spieler sieger = new Spieler();
        for (aktSpieler = 0; aktSpieler < Spieleranzahl; aktSpieler++) {
            textviewMID.setText(Spielerdaten[aktSpieler].getName() + " - " + Spielerdaten[aktSpieler].getSumme());

            //wenn nachfolgender Spieler höheren Score hat, dann ist er temporärer Sieger

            if (aktSpieler == 0) sieger = Spielerdaten[0];
            else if (Spielerdaten[aktSpieler - 1].getSumme() < Spielerdaten[aktSpieler].getSumme())
                sieger = Spielerdaten[aktSpieler];
        }
        textviewDOWN.setText("Damit ist " + sieger.getName() + " Sieger mit " + sieger.getSumme() + " Punkten");
    }}



    public int getRunden() {
        return Runden;
    }

    public void setRunden(int runden) {
        Runden = runden;
    }

    public int getVariante() {
        return Variante;
    }

    public void setVariante(int variante) {
        Variante = variante;
    }

    public int getAktSpieler() {
        return aktSpieler;
    }

    public void setAktSpieler(int aktSpieler) {
        this.aktSpieler = aktSpieler;
    }

    public int getSpieleranzahl() {
        return Spieleranzahl;
    }

    public void setSpieleranzahl(int spieleranzahl) {
        Spieleranzahl = spieleranzahl;
    }

    public Spieler[] getSpielderdaten() {
        return this.Spielerdaten;
    }

    public void setSpielderdaten(Spieler[] spielderdaten) {
        this.Spielerdaten = spielderdaten;
    }

}
```

Comment: please get used to write your code in english. that will be a lot better for you and your future partners to understand the written code

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: When neuesSpiel button is clicked mentioned methods will be called in the next order: variante(); spieleranzahl(); rundenanzahl(); spielernamen(); ingame();. Just write logs (Log.i("Tag", "methedName called") at the beginning of each method and you will see it. Each dialog you create in that methods overlays other dialog created in the previous method.

Comment: Next time i will write everything in english.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, your problem is that the dialogs are not shown in an synchronus manner. Try adding the specific methods in the previous `onClick()` methods.

So `spieleranzahl();` should go into the `onClick()` of `variante();`, `rundenanzahl();` in `spieleranzahl();` etc.

Your `ingame()` method is actually called, but in cause of the problem described before, the Runden variable (very bad practise to start a vaiable with an uppercase letter) is still 0 when you enter the while-loop. Therefor the loop never gets excecutet.

Comment: Thats a Good idea. But do you know Why ingame () not start?